# Cannot test code using App::error definitions in Laravel

Tags: php, exception, testing, laravel, phpunit

I have issues with testing Laravel applications that throws exceptions that are handled by App::errors declarations in global.php. When I perform a request to the controller with curl in the local environment everything works as expected but when doing the same request with the client in a unit test the exception is returned back instead of being caught by the app::error definition. I found this problem in a semi-large laravel application but I can replicate the behavior with newly generated Laravel project.

In my only controller I throw an exception like this:

```
throw new Exception("My test exception");
```

And the app::error declaration looks like this:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code) {

    Log::error($exception);
    return Response::make("YAY from app:error!", 500);
});
```

The error I get when running this is:

```
PHPUnit 4.2.6 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /Users/foo/testapp/testapp/phpunit.xml

E

Time: 64 ms, Memory: 9.75Mb

There was 1 error:

1) ExampleTest::testBasicExample
Exception: My test exception

/Users/foo/testapp/testapp/app/controllers/TestController.php:23
/Users/foo/testapp/testapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php:231
/Users/foo/testapp/testapp/bootstrap/compiled.php:5799
/Users/foo/testapp/testapp/bootstrap/compiled.php:5787
/Users/foo/testapp/testapp/bootstrap/compiled.php:4986
/Users/foo/testapp/testapp/bootstrap/compiled.php:5345
/Users/foo/testapp/testapp/bootstrap/compiled.php:5011
/Users/foo/testapp/testapp/bootstrap/compiled.php:4999
/Users/foo/testapp/testapp/bootstrap/compiled.php:722
/Users/foo/testapp/testapp/bootstrap/compiled.php:703
/Users/foo/testapp/testapp/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Client.php:81
/Users/foo/testapp/testapp/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Client.php:327
/Users/foo/testapp/testapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/ApplicationTrait.php:51
/Users/foo/testapp/testapp/app/tests/ExampleTest.php:12
```

The only bit of code I added to default TestCase.php is:

```
/**
 * Default preparation for each test
 */
public function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();
    Route::enableFilters();
}
```

The only code in the only test:

```
$this->call('GET', 'test'); // test is the only route existing in this app
```

Versions:

- Laravel (framework): 4.2.9
- PHPUnit: 4.2.6
- PHP: 5.5.15 OS:
- OSX 10.9.3

Do anybody know how to solve this problem so App:Error actually are triggered when testing? Or am I doing something wrong with the way throw and catch exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since you asked this question but hopefully this helps someone looking for an answer to this:

See Taylor Otwell's [comment on this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/633#issuecomment-15182879). Reproduced below:

"From looking at the PHPUnit source they are catching exceptions and swallowing them, so your handlers wouldn't be caught.

But, I think this can be solved by de-coupling your test. You really want to test the handler and that the exception is thrown totally separately anyways to isolate your tests. For instance:

```
App::error(function(ErrorType $e)
{
    App::make('ErrorTypeHandler')->handle($e);
});
```

Now you can write test cases for ErrorTypeHandler class separately from the rest of your application. Then check that proper exceptions are thrown by your app with @expectedException."

Simply put, implement your Exception handlers separately if you want to test them.